# Convert dtype object to period[M]

Tags: python, dtype

I have a column from a df like this of dtype object:
|date|
|-----|
|2020/01|
|2020/02|

And I want it to be the same, but with the date format period[M]. I have tried using groupby month, but did not work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if your dates are strings, transform them to datetime objects using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

If your dates have a datetime dtype, you can use [`.dt.to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df["date"] = df["date"].dt.to_period("M")
```

Comment: aaossa, there's no point answering duplicates, they get closed quickly. Just identify the close target.